# How to fetch the result of last row of conversation between each user?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mes_id  subject      mem_id       frm_id
55      Hi           329          401
72      Re: HI yhi   689          401
83      Re: HEY HI   401          329
68      HI yhi       401          689
59      Hi           401          1734
```

Hi,
please find my table response from below query from which I get the above response of 1 to 1 chat message.

```
SELECT mes_id,SUBJECT,mem_id,frm_id
FROM messages_system_new
WHERE frm_id = '401' AND mem_id !='401'
    AND trashed_user NOT LIKE '%401%'
    AND TYPE = 'message'
    AND FOLDER != 'saved' GROUP BY mem_id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT mes_id,SUBJECT,mem_id,frm_id
FROM messages_system_new
WHERE mem_id = '401' AND frm_id !='401'
    AND trashed_user NOT LIKE '%401%'
    AND TYPE = 'message'
    AND FOLDER != 'saved' GROUP BY frm_id
```

I just want the response which contain mes_id of 59,72,83 which is the last conversation between two users.

Please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1
WHERE (LEAST(mem_id, frm_id), GREATEST(mem_id, frm_id), mes_id) IN
  (
      SELECT  LEAST(mem_id, frm_id) as x, 
              GREATEST(mem_id, frm_id) as y, 
              MAX(mes_id) as msg_time
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY x, y
  )
ORDER BY Mes_ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77fa0/6)

Comment: thanks for your response but its for user 401 so where should i out that value?

Comment: what do you mean out the value for user 401?

Comment: I mean Now I logged in with user id 401 so I want all the latest conversation that I made with my friends

Comment: @user1743213 [Is this what you want? (*click this link*) It adds `AND MEM_ID = 401`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77fa0/9)

Comment: but using this will lost my conversation with 689. :(

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77fa0/13)

```
select t.*
from
    table1 t
    inner join (
        select  max(mes_id) as mes_id
        from table1
        group by least(mem_id, frm_id), greatest(mem_id, frm_id)
  ) s on t.mes_id = s.mes_id
where mem_id = 401 or frm_id = 401
order by mes_id
```